# error when storing a reference to a method in C++11

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, lambda

I want to work with lambda functions but I have a problem:

If I want to store a reference to a function declared in the "global scope" as std::function, there is no problem:

```
int myFunction()
{
    return 665;
}
int main()
{
    function<int()> functionRef = myFunction; //This works
}
```

If I want to do the same but storing a reference to a method:

```
//A class
class myClass
{
    public:
        int myMethod() 
        {
            return 666;
        }
};

//I create an instance:
myClass myInstance;

int main()
{
    function<int()> functionRef2 = myInstance.myMethod; //This doesn't work... why?
}
```

Gives me this error:

**error C3867: 'myClass::myMethod': function call missing argument list; use '&myClass::myMethod' to create a pointer to member**

I know that error happens when you call a function without the "()" but I'm not calling a function in this case. Just storing it on a variable.
I'm using Visual C++ 2010.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: myInstance.myMethod uses this call and is not of type int().

Comment: sorry I don't get it, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: myMethod depends on the instance it uses it and implicitly takes the 'this' pointer of the instance as an argument and that's why its signature isn't int(). I posted an answer that uses std::bind to bind the instance to the method which makes it callable as int()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `myClass::myMethod` is `int (myClass::*)()` and this is different from `int(*)()`

What you can use is

```
function<int()> functionRef2 = std::bind(&myClass::myMethod, &myInstance);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks for your help!. Now I have 1 more question about this: Can I use the bind function with the first example? Replacing this: 'function<int()> functionRef = myFunction;'
with something like this?: std::bind(&myFunction, &myFunction);

Comment: Yes you can do something like: std::bind(myFunction); look at std::bind documentation to understand how it works,  you can do much more things with it

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `bind`, you can use a lambda:

```
function<int()> functionRef2 = [&](int n){ return myInstance.myMethod(n); };
```